# Creating a floating view on iPad

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

My iPad application has a SplitViewController, a MasterViewController and a DetailViewController. From the DetailViewController, I need to create a temporary view (managed with a PaletteViewController: UIViewController, and designed in a xib file) that the user can move on the screen to be able to see what content is backwards.

in DetailViewController.m:

```
@synthesize paletteViewController=_paletteViewController;

(...)

- (IBAction) loadPalette: (id) sender{
    if (_paletteViewController == nil) {
        self.paletteViewController = [[PaletteViewController alloc] init];
    }
    self.paletteViewController.delegate=self;
    [self.paletteViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.paletteViewController animated:YES];

(...)
```

I get an error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller .

Any idea?

Comment: Have you presented the paletteViewController twice in a row w/o having dismissed it?  You can test with 'if (self == self.paletteViewController.presentingViewController) ...'

Comment: you were right, nice shot GoZoner!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in your `paletteViewController` and you are presenting modally paletteViewController over plaetteViewController . how is it possible.you can present paletteViewController over detailview or something(some paarent view).